Why is there no formula for implied volatility?
While there are methods, none is a closed form solution. My question is aimed at mathematic problems, rather than the practical.

i can't think of anything more mathematical than an entire branch of mathematics (numerical analysis) being invented to solve exactly the kind of problem you refer to. put another way: in mathematics, closed form solutions are the exceptions, not the rule.

To add to the statement by @user35980: IV extraction is a problem that does not lend itself to a closed form expressions and hence requires approximate solutions via root search.

I would also like to add that when you think about it, all methods you implement on a computer are approximate numerical methods. What is really important is how accurate and fast the method is. But I see where you are coming from, from a mathematical perspective, where a simple closed formula makes the calculations easier.

Too long for a comment, too short for an answer:
It depends what you mean by closed form solution. Do you consider $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ a closed form solution?
See for example this recent paper on a closed form solution for IV, which is I believe not the only 'closed form solution' for IV: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3573239
I am not sure if the BS call/put price formula is an analytic function of the IV actually, but if it is I suppose the Lagrange Inversion Theorem could also give you a closed form solution.

TLDR: because before electronic computers became widely available, a paper treating the output of a root finder as a market observable might have difficulty getting through peer review.
Random reflections about then and now: I was recently showing off my grandfather's books (https://search.worldcat.org/title/927133 et al ) and we made the following observation - back in those days, people tried hard to find closed-form solutions, because numerical calculations were expensive, often too expensive. As a consequence, people sometimes tweaked their models so they would represent the reality less accurately, but had a pretty closed-form solution.
Take bond yields, for example. They're so easy to get these days, people often forget that they're almost always the output from an iterative  root solver. Before everyone had access to cheap computers, people used actual paper books where you looked up the nearest coupon and maturity in a table and interpolated.
You may like the book, When Computers Were Human
Conclusion: whenever I see a pretty closed-form solution, I can't but wonder a little whether someone took some shortcuts to oversimplify the model assumptions in order to reduce numerical calculations.
